# Symfony normalize numbered property like addressLine1

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, normalize

I'm trying to normalize an Address object with the Symfony [Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) but the following property is not normalized correctly.

Address object

```
final class Address {
    ...
    private ?string $addressLine1;
    private ?string $addressLine2;
}
```

My Serializer looks like this

```
$normalizers = [
    new BackedEnumNormalizer(),
    new ArrayDenormalizer(),
    new ObjectNormalizer(
        null,
        new CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter(),
        null,
        new ReflectionExtractor()
    ),
];
$encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];

$this->serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders)
```

Normalizing

```
$this->serializer->normalize($address)
```

When normalizing the `$addressLine1` the array property is presented as `address_line1` but should return `address_line_1`, same goes for `$addressLine2`.

Any push in the right direction will be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I found a solution for the problem. I found somewhere that a property name can be overridden with PHP Annotations. So I started implementing a new `NameConverter`

```
$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));

$metadataAwareNameConverter = new MetadataAwareNameConverter($classMetadataFactory, new CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter());

$normalizers = [
    new BackedEnumNormalizer(),
    new ArrayDenormalizer(),
    new ObjectNormalizer(
        null,
        $metadataAwareNameConverter,
        null,
        new ReflectionExtractor()
    ),
];
$encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];

$this->serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
```

Previously I only had the `CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter`. I found out that I had to use the `MetadataAwareNameConverter` so I could add a Annotation to the property.

```
final class Address {
    ...
    #[SerializedName('address_line_1')]
    private ?string $addressLine1;
    #[SerializedName('address_line_2')]
    private ?string $addressLine2;
}
```

Then I could add the `CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter` as a default name converter the `MetadataAwareNameConverter` as a fallback.

This went in as an argument on the `ObjectNormalizer`.

I did had to add the `doctrine/annotations` as a composer requirement which wasn't really wanted.